# How to include js from js , using IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

I try the code provided at https://stackoverflow.com/a/950146/151453 , and I successfully verified that I can load my `t2.js` from `t1.js` . However, `t2.js` finish-loading callback works only for Chrome (v26), Firefox （v17), and IE10, **but NOT for Microsoft IE8 (Windows 7)** .

The symptom on IE8 is: The callback `start_deco()` is never called.

How can I achieve the same result in IE8? Thank you.

==== Code below ====

t1.html :

```
<html>
<head></head>

<body>
Hello!

<script src="t1.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

t1.js :

```
// loadScript function provided by https://stackoverflow.com/a/950146/151453
function loadScript(url, callback)
{
    // adding the script tag to the head as suggested before
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = url;

    // then bind the event to the callback function 
    // there are several events for cross browser compatibility
    //script.onreadystatechange = callback;  // chj: !!!
    script.onload = callback;

    // fire the loading
    head.appendChild(script);
}

function start_deco()
{
    alert('Done t2.js.');
    loadScript('t3.js.');
}

loadScript('t2.js', start_deco) // wish to load jquery.js etc
```

t2.js :

```
console.log('Loading t2.js...')
```

t3.js :

```
console.log('Loading t3.js...')
```

[image]

**============== UPDATE1 =================**

On IE8, if I enable `script.onreadystatechange = callback;` in `loadScript()` , the alert box does pop up, however, calling `loadScript('t3.js.');` fails with "Not implemented error" on that line so that t3.js fails to load. Image below:

[image]

Comment: You may be running into security issues with running from a file:// URL in IE8. Try running the same code from a web server and see if it works.

Comment: Are you getting any JavaScript errors in IE8? (red X at bottom-right)

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan is right - do you have the IE dev tools or Firebug lite installed? Take a look at the console and see what's reported there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh, I got it. It was my fault! The loadScript() provide by https://stackoverflow.com/a/950146/151453 is utterly workable on IE8 and Firefox, Chrome.

And, in order for it to work in IE9+, I have to follow this Microsoft suggestion: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh180173(v=vs.85).aspx .

It is my fault to comment out the `script.onreadystatechange = callback;` statement.

The "Not implemented" error shown on my IE8 console is due to missing `callback` parameter when calling `loadScript('t3.js.');` .

So, to fix this problem, I should add a line to loadScript(), the final result is:

```
function loadScript(url, callback)
{
    // adding the script tag to the head as suggested before
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = url;

    if(!callback) callback = function(){}; // ★★★★★★★★★ JUST ADD THIS LINE!

    // bind the event to the callback function 
    if(script.addEventListener) {
      script.addEventListener("load", callback, false); // IE9+, Chrome, Firefox
    } 
    else if(script.readyState) {
      script.onreadystatechange = callback; // IE8
    }

    // fire the loading
    head.appendChild(script);
}
```

Verified on IE8, IE9, Firefox 17, Chrome 27 .

Comment: I had a similar issue, for inline js I used the createElement('script') but for cross browser external js i just did this: document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="' + url[1] + '"><\/script>');

Answer (score 1):

IE8 and older handle the `script` object a bit differently - they don't expose an `onLoad` event but an `onReadyStateChange` event. You can take a look at Mootools' `Asset.javascript` function at https://github.com/mootools/mootools-more/blob/master/Source/Utilities/Assets.js for a good example. You're mainly looking for this part:

```
if (!script.addEventListener){
  script.addEvent('readystatechange', function(){
    if (['loaded', 'complete'].contains(this.readyState)) load.call(this);
  });
} else {
  script.addEvent('load', load);
}
```

It should be noted of course that situations like this are one of the prime reasons for always using a library like Mootools or jQuery, to exactly avoid problems like this.

Answer (score 0):

I know it isn't from js, but is this an option?

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        Hello!

        <script src="t1.js"></script>
        <!--[if IE 8]>
            <script src="t2.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry, I need to load a js from another js, not from html, to avoid static html maintenance nightmare.